# Module stops working when importing it in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have python3 code in the following structure:

```
/main.py
/generated/a.py
/generated/b.py
```

Where `a.py` has:

```
import b
```

and `main.py` has:

```
from generated import a
```

The following command works:

```
python3 generated/a.py
```

But the following command doesn't work:

```
python3 main.py
```

Due to this error:

```
File "...../generated/a.py", line 3, in <module>
    import b 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'
```

Why does `generated/a.py` stop working when importing it as part of `main.py`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,if you want to "python3 main.py" to work,u could use follow structure

```
/main.py
/generated/a.py
/generated/b.py
/generated/__init__.py(blank)
```

change a.py import ,should be follow not "import b"

```
from generated import b
```

why does "python3 generated/a.py" work and "python3 main.py" doesnt work.

`python3 generated/a.py`
It actually run "a.py",because it's the same level with "b.py",so just import should be fine.

`python3 main.py`
It actually run "main.py",because `from generated import a`."main.py" actually look like this

main.py

```
import b
```

because "main.py" is not the same level with "b.py" so it can't find the module

Answer (score 0):

Your original code relied on a Python feature that was removed in Python3: **Implicit Relative Import**.

In Python 3 you either need to change the `import b` lines in the modules inside `generated/` into explicit relative imports like `from . import b` or into absolute imports like `import generated.b`.

Implicit relative imports have some downsides. There are numerous articles about the reasons it was removed and the articles should be easy to find if you search for "python implicit relative import".